# Relation between thermal energy and mass

Tags: thermodynamics

"Suppose you have a glass of water and a beaker of water. They are at the same temperature. The beaker contains twice as much water as the glass. The average kinetic energy of the water molecules is the same in both containers, since they are the same temperature. But there are twice as many water molecules in the beaker as there are in the glass. So the total kinetic energy of the water molecules in the beaker is twice as large as that of the water molecules in the glass. The water in the beaker has twice as much thermal energy as the water in the glass has. If the temperature doesn’t change but the mass of the object increases, the thermal energy in the object increases.  A relatively small sample at a somewhat high temperature such as a cup of tea at its boiling temperature could have less thermal energy than a larger sample such as a pool that's at a lower temperature. If the cup of boiling tea is placed next to the freezing pool, the cup of tea will freeze first because it has less thermal energy than the pool."

So I saw these examples online and I had a doubt whether heat flows from one body to another even if temperature is same just because the larger sample has higher thermal energy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I saw these examples online and I had a doubt whether heat flows
> from one body to another even if temperature is same just because the
> larger sample has higher thermal energy?

There's no NET flow of heat between bodies at the same temperature, regardless of their size.

How do we know this? The Laws of Thermodynamics.

How do we know they're true? Hundreds of years of observation without a single violation noted.